# Copy constructor of ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> not Working Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a copy to an Array List of Array Lists, but when doing so the addresses of all the individual elements are staying the same.

```
copySorted = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(origSorted);
```

I would expect to generate a copy of origSorted without references to the original, but instead whenever I make a change to copySorted, it ends up happening to origSorted as well.  I also tried the .clone() function with the same results.

Comment: You've made a "shallow copy" so you have a new arraylist full of original array lists. You're looking for a "deep copy".

Answer (score 1):

It's not the changes to `copySorted` you're seeing, it's changes to the inner lists which are shared between the outer lists. If you want them to be completely distinct, you'll need to copy each one individually:

```
copySorted = new ArrayList<>(origSorted.size());
for (List<String> inner : origSorted) {
    copySorted.add(new ArrayList<>(inner));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you creat your ArrayList then creat your new arrayList by using the keyWord "new" so the new arraylist will be a new object seprate from the first arraylist like this:

```
ArrayList<String> myFirstArrayList = new ArrayList<>();//creat my first arrayList
    //add some objects
    myFirstArrayList.add("1");
    myFirstArrayList.add("2");
    myFirstArrayList.add("3");
    //print it
    System.out.println(myFirstArrayList);//[1, 2, 3]
    //creating a new arrayList by coping the first but we create a new arrayList by using the keyword "New"
    ArrayList<String> newArrayList= new ArrayList<>(myFirstArrayList);
    //print new arraylist
    System.out.println(newArrayList);//[1, 2, 3]
    //make some change in the new arraylist
    newArrayList.remove(1);
    //print the

    System.out.println(newArrayList);//[1, 3]
    System.out.println(myFirstArrayList);//[1, 2, 3]
    //my original arraylist still not changed b'z the two objects of arraylists are seperate.
```